# Problema cargando layout (xml) - Error en RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, recyclerview

Tengo un par de layouts donde trabajo con `RecyclerView` (`Xamarin.Android C#`) pero en todos los que tiene el Recycler desde el día de ayer me empezó a dar el siguiente error en el area donde debería estar mi RecyclerView:

> No se pudieron cargar los controles de la biblioteca de compatibilidad
> con android. El problema puede corregirse con una restauracion de
> NuGet.

Diseño Xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                p1:orientation="horizontal"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/LayoutFondo"
                p1:background="@drawable/ftb"
                p1:minWidth="25px"
                p1:minHeight="25px"
                p1:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                p1:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    p1:id="@+id/RecyclerViewClientes"
                    p1:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Ya me había pasado hace mucho tiempo pero usando este comando en el PM console de NuGet se había solucionado:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Pero ahora ya lo he intentado varias veces y no funciona. Ideas?

El RecyclerView me lo muestra de esta manera:

[image: Mensaje]

[image: Error]

Comment: ¿Ya probaste desde Build>Clean Project y luego Build>Rebuild Project?

Comment: Si ya probe eso.

Comment: 1. Verifica que las versiones y dependencias de los paquetes de Nuget sean los correctos. 2. Intenta eliminar manualmente las carpetas Bin y Obj generadas en la solución del proyecto. 3. Verifica que las librerías son compatibles con el Target de Android que tienes seleccionado para la compilacion en el proyecto. 4. Haz clean y rebuild. Si nada de esto funciona, ve al archivo package.config y verifica que no hayan 2 versiones iguales de un paquete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Listo.**

Tambien tenia instalado el Nugget `AndroidX` y parece que estaba causando conflicto (aunque estos errores igual a veces me salían, mucho antes de implementar AndroidX en el proyecto -raro-) así que lo solucione sustituyendo en mi diseño xml, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    p1:orientation="vertical"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="300dp"
                    p1:id="@+id/LayoutAgarraNewsFeedI"
                    p1:background="@drawable/ftb"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    p1:layout_marginRight="0dp">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        p1:id="@+id/RecyclerNewsFeedI"
                        p1:scrollbars="vertical"
                        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                        p1:layout_height="300dp"/>

                </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Y quedo mucho mejor.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ese error se soluciona haciendo una restauracion de la libreria dañada. Te dejo un link donde te enseña a ver el historial de errores, detectar que libreria es la dañada, descargar y reinstalar dicha libreria.

[Te dejo un link donde te enseña a ver el historial de errores, detectar que libreria es, la dañada, descargar y reinstalar dicha libreria.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors)

Espero que te sirva

Saludos

Comment: Hola @Rixos, gracias por el articulo, sin embargo ahi se menciona la solución para cuando te da un error especifico: Download failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository.    

En mi caso no tengo ese error y considero no aplica a lo mismo por lo que no sabría como implementarlo para mi caso. 

Pero gracias de igual manera.